# How to animate collection of images from bottom in swift4

Tags: ios, swift4

First time I am trying to do animation.Here my task is collection of images should animate from bottom.I am trying to follow one link "https://www.yudiz.com/uiview-animation-with-swift-4/" In this example,How the images are animating from bottom to top, that's what how I want.I did till the collection of images.Next on ward ,how today and all I don't even have an idea.If anyone help's me to do this ,would be great.Thankyou in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Show your attempt

Comment: I did till the collection of images, and I am using XIB's